# Convert Stopwatch to int

Tags: c#, int, stopwatch

I have a little snag , I ought to Convert my Stopwatch into Int ,

`Stopwatch czasAlg = new Stopwatch();`

czasAlg.Start();
//Do something
czasAlg.Stop();

Int32 mojCzas = Convert.ToInt32(czasAlg); //I try to convert but it does't work.

// Int32 mojCzas = Convert.ToInt32(czasAlg.ToString()); //It does't work too.

Any Ideas to solve the problem ?

Comment: Umm.. why exactly do you need to do that? If you were told to, it's pure prank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting together the pieces from your question and comments, it seems you want this:

```
Stopwatch czasAlg = new Stopwatch();
czasAlg.Start(); 
//Do something 
czasAlg.Stop();
double timeInSecondsPerN=czasAlg.Elapsed.TotalSeconds/n;
```

Answer (score 4):

Converting a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to an [Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) makes absolutely no sense. To get the ellapsed time you could use the [ElapsedMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds.aspx) property. So the usual pattern would be:

```
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Do something you would like to measure
watch.Stop();
long totalMilliseconds = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine("The operation executed in {0} ms", totalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: I must convert to int because I have to divide czasAlg/n ,

Comment: Where n is number of elements in table

Comment: @Konrad, a Stopwatch is a class (reference type) while an Int32 is a structure (value type). Converting between those two types is absolutely meaningless.

Comment: If you want to calculate some mean value then store the elapsed times in an integer array and calculate the average. If you don't want to do this then please explain what are you trying to do and please don't say *I am trying to divide a Stopwatch by n* as it makes no sense.

Comment: When I write this: int mojCzas = czasAlg.ElapsedMilliseconds; the"ElapsedMilliseconds" is underlined

Comment: Yes indeed, I made a mistake. The ElapsedMilliseconds property is of type Int64 and not Int32. I've updated my answer. It should be: `long mojCzas = czasAlg.ElapsedMilliseconds`

Comment: I try to measure time of  countingSort algorithm for arrays with 10^2 up to 10^8 elements and generate table with time comparison.

Comment: OK, so every time you call the algorithm, store the result (total milliseconds) into an integer array.

Answer (score 1):

czasAlg is an object of type Stopwatch. You will not be able to convert it to Int. Check the documentation of StopWatch class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

StopWatch class has properties like Elapsed, ElapsedMilliseconds, ElapsedTicks etc. You can obtain the values of these properties, which ever you need.